# Uploading to Google Cloud Storage using Blobstore: Blobstore doesn't retain file name upon upload

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, blobstore

I'm trying to upload to GCS using the Blobstore. I have set the GCS bucket name while generating the upload url, and the file gets uploaded successfully.

In the upload handler, `blobInfo.getFilename()` returns the right file name. But the file actually got saved in the GCS bucket in some different file name. Each time, the file name is some random hash like this one:

```
L2FwcGhvc3RpbmdfcHJvZC9ibG9icy9BRW5CMlVvbi1XNFEyWEJkNGlKZHNZRlJvTC0wZGlXVS13WTF2c0g0LXdzcEVkaUNEbEEyc3daS3Vham1MVlZzNXlCSk05ZnpKc1RudDJpajF1TmxwdWhTd2VySVFLdUw3US56ZXFHTEZSLVoxT3lablBI
```

Is this how it will work? Is this an anomaly?

I store the file name to the datastore based on the data returned from `blobInfo.getFilename()`, which is the correct value of file name. But I'm unable to access the file using the `GcsFilename` since the file is stored in GCS with that random hash as file name.

Any pointers would be greatly helpful.

Thanks!

*PS:* [The blobstore page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/) says that BlobInfo is currently not available for GCS objects. But BlobInfo.getFilename returns the right value for me. Is that something wrong from my end?

Comment: @Alex - This should be an answer, not a comment. It would help to close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's how it works, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/fileinfoclas ...:

> FileInfo metadata is not persisted to datastore [...] You must save
>   the `gs_object_name` yourself in your upload handler or this data will
>   be lost

I personally recommend that new applications use https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/ directly, rather than the blobstore emulation on top of it.

The latter is currently provided essentially only for (limited, partial) backwards compatibility: it's not really all that suitable for new applications.